# MongoDB queries with null value

Tags: mongodb, null

My collection (MongoDB v 2.0.2) has following records:

```
db.organization.find({})
{ "_id" : 1001, "path" : [ ], "parent" : null }
{ "_id" : 1002, "path" : [ 1001 ], "parent" : NumberLong(1001) }
```

`organization` has indexes:

```
db.organization.ensureIndex({"path":1});
db.organization.ensureIndex({"parent":1},{sparse:false});
```

(note I put awarnes `sparse : false` - to grant that null is indexed)
But, executing:

```
db.organization.find({"parent":null})
```

Returns empty set. What is wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you still running into issues with this?  Can you give the output of db.system.indexes.find() as well as db.organization.find().explain()?

Comment: @Barrie, right now I cannot reproduce this error. I'm pretty sure that it was reached by multiple applying of `js` scripts from command line tool. Those time I've started `explain` to recognize error, but it shown normal usage of indexes

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue. After reading the following documents

- [querying and nulls](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying+and+nulls)
- [BSON specification](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)

I tried to query for the different BSON element types and found that my null was represented as a BSON element type 6 (undefined, deprecated) instead of the expected BSON element type 10 (null).

```
db.collection.find({ field: { "$type" : 6} };
```

Comment: based on the first link, I think it should be `db.collection.find({ field: { "$type" : 10} };`

Comment: @AbdelHady: Perhaps the documents represent a simplified version of reality. I just had to use `{ field: { $type: 6 } }` in an `update` where I really want to say `{ field: null }`.

Comment: @AbdelHady: Scratch that, I think `{ $type: 10 }` really is the right thing and I'm just confusing myself.

Comment: But I tried it myself in my database, `{field: null}` gave the same result as `{field: { "$type" : 10} }` but `{field: { "$type" : 6} }` didn't. And also, the first link in the answer here states that "The `{ cancelDate : { $type: 10 } }` query matches documents that contains the cancelDate field whose value is null only;"

Comment: to find null bson types as @Abdel Hady said, use db.collection.find({ field: { "$type" : 10} };

Answer (score 6):

Just checked following script at 2.0 and 2.0.2:

```
db.items.insert({ "_id" : 1001, "path" : [ ], "parent" : null })
db.items.insert({ "_id" : 1002, "path" : [ 1001 ], "parent" : NumberLong(1001) })
db.items.ensureIndex({"path":1});
db.items.ensureIndex({"parent":1},{sparse:false});
db.items.find({"parent":null})
```

actually returns one document that you expect:

```
{ "_id" : 1001,
  "path" : [],
  "parent" : null }
```

Also you can look into this doc about [querying and nulls](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying+and+nulls), probably should help you avoid possible future mistakes.

Comment: it is some magic. You example with `items` works, but mine sucks.